# Google sheets dates, stored as strings by toString(), are not recognized as dates when written back into a cell?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a sheet that adds several thousand values per day. To keep it small and nimble, it regularly stores rows of data as comma separated values on a separate sheet. I loop through each row using toString() on all the cells.

When retrieving and reprinting the needed data to a new sheet, the sheets do not recognize the strings as dates.
e.g. Fri Mar 29 2019 13:45:06 GMT-0700 (PDT)

My workaround is slicing the strings when retrieving them, I am just wondering why they don't recognize the standard date strings as dates.

```
function compressData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var arr = sheet.getRange(1,1,2,2).getValues();
  var arrNew = []; 
  var arrRow =[];
  var arrExpanded;

  for (var i in arr) {
    for (var x in arr[i]) {
      arrRow.push(arr[x][i]);
    }
    arrNew.push([arrRow[i].toString()]);
  } 
  // stores each row of the original array as a 
  // comma separated string in a new array

  sheet.getRange(1, 3, arrNew.length, arrNew[0].length).setValues(arrNew); 
  // writes the new array to a new range
}

function expandData(){
  // prints the arrays onto a new range and the new date 
  // cell isn't recognized as a date

  var arrExpanded = [];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var arrCompressed = sheet.getRange(1,3,2,1).getValues();

  for (var i in arrCompressed) {
    var arrTemp = arrCompressed.toString().split(',');
    arrExpanded.push(arrTemp);
  }
  // rebuilds the 2d array

 sheet.getRange(1, 4, arrExpanded.length, arrExpanded[0].length).setValues(arrExpanded); 
}
```

Comment: Would you please give an example of the date string?

Comment: Thanks. Edited. Fri Mar 29 2019 13:45:06 GMT-0700 (PDT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You extract date values from a string, and are wondering why Google Sheets doesn't recognize the standard date strings as dates.

The reason is that the date that you see on-screen is actually a number, [milliseconds from the Unix epoch](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#datetime_serial_numbers). It is merely **formatted** to display so that it "looks like" a date consisting of text.

To convert a date string to a value that Google Sheets will recognise as a date, you need to convert it. The following code provides a simple example:

In the screenshot below, the value in Cell B1 is a string; the value is cell C1 is a date value. Note the actual data value (number) displayed in cell C5 (this cell is formatted as 'Number');

---

```
function so5842277201() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "Sheet1";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  var datestring = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  Logger.log(datestring);

  var date01 = new Date(datestring);
  Logger.log(date01);
  var date02 = Utilities.formatDate(date01,"GMT-7", "EEE MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  var newdaterange = sheet.getRange("C1");
  newdaterange.setValue(date02);
}
```

---

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Tedinoz. I see that I wasn't clear with my question. I was wondering why the developers had not programmed in the cells to convert these strings to dates. There are a slew of different strings (1-11-2011, 5/5/18 etc.) that will be converted to dates when formatting the cells, and I thought that the js date string would be a recognized string format.

Comment: I wouldn't have noticed that the format as date option didn't work on them, except  for when putting into pivot tables or charts, it didn't recognize them.

Comment: @DanielDavidson I see what you mean, but... 1) the programming to do that would be eye-watering, 2) how would a sheet "know" 1-11-2011 (as a string)  = 1 November 2001 Vs 11 January 2011), 3) what if one wanted the cell content to be a string - not possible! I strongly agree that it is always worth wondering why can't a sheet just <insert here what we would like it to do> - that's how features are developed. But in this case, I don't think recognising date strings as dates is a goer.